Desmond treatment of long-range interactions in solvent-free MD of charged systems
I'm trying to perform MD simulations of solvent-free system with Desmond of charged systems (DNA/RNA molecules). I saw that Desmond is using u-series method for treating long-range interactions. Actually, I created a system with System Builder that doesn't have solvent and has a buffer size of 700x700x700, no counterions and no salt are present, just my charged nucleic acid (663 atoms, on which I've added 5 negative charges on the OP2 atom). I did different MD simulation with different cutoff radius =30, 50, 70, 90, and 200 ang.
The system didn't report errors during the calculations and by checking the trajectories and in the case of the one simulated with a cutoff=200ang a shrinkage of the structure was observed. Is there a maximum/minimum value for short-range interactions cutoff in the case of solvent-free MD? I've read on publications that Desmond relies on u-series type which is an alternative to Ewald-summation methods. Could you please explain to me the possible problems/solutions for performing solvent- and counterions-free MD in Desmond with charged systems?
